# How to get input text from theme options on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, textinput

I just set up a new input text option into my theme-options.php file, which is similar to the twenty eleven theme code.

Here are parts of my theme-options.php code in regards to the input, I'm looking for a way to get the input that users enter into the 'fact' text and show it on the index.php page:

```
function themename_theme_options_init() {

register_setting(
    'themename_options',       // Options group, see settings_fields() call in themename_theme_options_render_page()
    'themename_theme_options', // Database option, see themename_get_theme_options()
    'themename_theme_options_validate' // The sanitization callback, see themename_theme_options_validate()
);

// Register our settings field group
add_settings_section(
    'general', // Unique identifier for the settings section
    '', // Section title (we don't want one)
    '__return_false', // Section callback (we don't want anything)
    'theme_options' // Menu slug, used to uniquely identify the page; see themename_theme_options_add_page()
);

// Register our individual settings fields
add_settings_field( 'facts', __( 'Facts',     'themename' ), 'themename_settings_field_facts', 'theme_options', 'general' );
add_settings_field( 'link_color', __( 'Link Color',     'themename' ), 'themename_settings_field_link_color', 'theme_options', 'general' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'themename_theme_options_init' );
```

Returns the default facts for Theme Name, based on color scheme:

```
function themename_get_default_facts( $color_scheme = null ) {
if ( null === $color_scheme ) {
    $options = themename_get_theme_options();
    $color_scheme = $options['color_scheme'];
}

$color_schemes = themename_color_schemes();
if ( ! isset( $color_schemes[ $color_scheme ] ) )
    return false;

return $color_schemes[ $color_scheme ]['default_facts'];
}
```

Renders the Facts setting field.

```
function themename_settings_field_facts() {
$options = themename_get_theme_options();
?>
<input type="text" name="themename_theme_options[facts]" id="facts" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $options['facts'] ); ?>" />
<br />
<span><?php printf( __( 'Default facts: %s', 'themename' ), '<span id="default-facts">' . themename_get_default_facts ( $options['color_scheme'] ) . '</span>' ); ?></span>
<?php
}
```

Sanitize and validate form input:

```
function themename_theme_options_validate( $input ) {
$output = $defaults = themename_get_default_theme_options();

// Color scheme must be in our array of color scheme options
if ( isset( $input['color_scheme'] ) && array_key_exists( $input['color_scheme'], themename_color_schemes() ) )
    $output['color_scheme'] = $input['color_scheme'];

// Facts must be characters.
if ( isset( $input['facts'] ) )
    $output['facts'] = '' . ( ltrim( $input['facts'], '' ) );

// Our defaults for the link color may have changed, based on the color scheme.
$output['link_color'] = $defaults['link_color'] = themename_get_default_link_color( $output['color_scheme'] );

// Link color must be 3 or 6 hexadecimal characters
if ( isset( $input['link_color'] ) && preg_match( '/^#?([a-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$/i', $input['link_color'] ) )
    $output['link_color'] = '#' . strtolower( ltrim( $input['link_color'], '#' ) );

return apply_filters( 'themename_theme_options_validate', $output, $input, $defaults );
}
```

Implements theme options into Theme Customizer:

```
function themename_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogname' )->transport = 'postMessage';
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogdescription' )->transport = 'postMessage';

$options  = themename_get_theme_options();
$defaults = themename_get_default_theme_options();

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'themename_theme_options[facts]', array(
    'default'           => themename_get_default_facts( $options['color_scheme'] ),
    'type'              => 'option',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
    'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
) );

}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'themename_customize_register' );
```

Thank you to anyone that can help :)
Thanks!  I got it working :D

Answer (score 0):

```
----------
<?php
/**
 * Theme Options
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * 
 */


/* Write the name and the variable_name in which you want to store the data using theme options in the array $options_array */
$options_array = array(
            'Facebook URL'=>'facebook_url',
        );


function my_theme_options_init() {

    // If we have no options in the database, let's add them now.
    if ( false === my_theme_options() )
        add_option( 'my_theme_options', my_default_theme_options() );

    register_setting(
        'my_options',       // Options group, see settings_fields() call in theme_options_render_page()
        'my_theme_options' // Database option, see my_theme_options()
    );
    global $options_array;
    foreach ($options_array as $key=>$option ){
        register_setting( 'my_options', $option);
    }

}


add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_theme_options_init' );






function my_theme_options_add_page() {
    $theme_page = add_theme_page(
        'myers themeing',   // Name of page
        'myers themeing',   // Label in menu
        'edit_theme_options',                    // Capability required
        'my_options',                         // Menu slug, used to uniquely identify the page
        'my_theme_options_render_page' // Function that renders the options page
    );

    if ( ! $theme_page )
        return;


}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_theme_options_add_page' );



function my_default_schemes() {
    $default_array = array('value' => 'Default_theme',
            'label' => __( 'Default_theme', 'my' ),
            'thumbnail' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/images/my.png' 
            );
    global $options_array;
    foreach ($options_array as $key=>$option ){
        $default_array[$option] =' ';
    }

    $default_scheme_options = array(
        'Default_theme' => $default_array,
    );

    return apply_filters( 'my_default_schemes', $default_scheme_options );
}



function my_default_theme_options() {
    $default_theme_options = array( 'default_scheme' => 'Default_theme' );
    global $options_array;  
    foreach ($options_array as $key=>$option ){
        $default_theme_options[$option] = my_default( $option,'Default_theme' );
    }   

    return apply_filters( 'my_default_theme_options', $default_theme_options );
}



function my_default( $option ,$default_scheme = null ) {
    if ( null === $default_scheme ) {
        $options = my_theme_options();
        $default_scheme = $options['default_scheme'];
    }

    $default_schemes = my_default_schemes();
    if ( ! isset( $default_schemes[ $default_scheme ] ) )
        return false;

    return $default_schemes[ $default_scheme ][$option];
}



function my_theme_options() {
    return get_option( 'my_theme_options', my_default_theme_options() );
}

function my_theme_options_render_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <?php screen_icon(); ?>
        <h2><?php printf( __( '%s Theme Options', 'my' ), get_current_theme() ); ?></h2>
        <?php settings_errors(); ?>
        <hr>

        <div id="theme_option_main">

            <h2>myers themeing</h2>
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="options.php">
            <?php

                settings_fields( 'my_options' );
                $options = my_theme_options();
                $default_options = my_default_theme_options();
                global $options_array;  
                foreach ($options_array as $key=>$option ){
                    do_settings_sections($option);
                }   

            ?>

                <table class="form-table">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><?php _e( "(Use ' http:// ' for Hyperlinks)", 'my' ); ?></th>
                        <td>
                            <fieldset>
                            </fieldset>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php   
                            foreach ($options_array as $key=>$option ){

                         ?>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row"><?php _e( $key, 'my' ); ?></th>
                            <td>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <legend class="screen-reader-text"><span><?php _e( $key, 'my' ); ?></span></legend>
                                    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $option ?>" id="<?php echo $option ?>" class="large-text" value="<?php echo get_option($option); ?>"></input>
                                </fieldset>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    <?php } ?>


                </table>
                <?php submit_button(); ?>
            </form>



        </div>
    </div>  

    <?php
}
?>
```

copy the code and create a new theme options file. Add the name and the variable_name in the options array in the file and you are good to go.

Don't forget to link this file in your functions.php
To link it just add the following code in your functions.php

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/inc/your_file_name.php' );
```